# how to call request mapping method level through class level RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I did one simple program using spring. I got answer for method level RequestMapping when i did not use class level RequestMapping. But i want to use both class level and method level RequestMapping.

This is my controller code

```
package com.birthid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/classLevel")
public class Controaller1 
{
     @RequestMapping("/spring")
     public ModelAndView display(@RequestParam("name") String name)
     {
         ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("view");
         model.addObject("msg", name);
         return model;
     }      
}
```

html code

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>Hello App Engine</title>
</head>

<body>
   <h1>valith web application!</h1>
   <form action="/classLevel" method="get">
      name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br>
      <input type="submit" value="clik me"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

when i give this url in address bar. i got exact output. `http:localhost:8888/classLevel/spring?name=john`

but when i press button where i design in html page, that is giving error.

Comment: Well, your form action is /classLevel, and your method is mapped to /classLevel/spring, so that's quite expected, isn't it?

Comment: i don't know how to map first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well simply the problem is with your form action, you have `action="/classLevel"` wich should be `action="/classLevel/spring"` because your method have `/spring` as RequestMapping so change :

```
<form action="/classLevel" method="get">
```

To :

```
<form action="/classLevel/spring" method="get">
```

Because as you did in your url test the method call should be : `/classLevel/spring`.

Take a look at [**Mapping Requests With @RequestMapping**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping) section of ***Spring Docs*** for further information.

Comment: ok. if i have more than one local RequestMapping means.. Then how can i give the path

Comment: Ok i got answer as you said. But if i have more than one method level mapping means,then how can i map?..

Comment: It's just similar to REST url, give the Controller Class RequestMapping then the RequestMapping of your mthod: `/classLevel/spring` for example.

Comment: Take a look at the link in my EDIT it will give you the explanation you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

***As you know:***
In the Spring MVC you can return view as a `String` or `ModelAndView` object.

***IMPORTANT NOTE:***

In both cases you have to pay attention to **relative/absolute path**:

1. If you declare `/` in the beginning of the view name, you are using **absolute path**.
   Namely it does not matter **class level** `@RequestMapping` and directly introduce itself as the **final view name**.
2. If you **do not** declare `/` in the beginning of the view name, you are using **relative path** (relative to the class path) and therefore it **appends** to the **class level** `@RequestMapping` to construct **final view name**.

So, you have to consider the above notes when use the Spring MVC.

**Example:**
1. create two HTML file `test1.html` and `test2.html` in the `static` folder of spring (boot) structure:
Please note that the **class level** `@RequestMapping` behaves as a **folder** path in the case of **relative** path.

```
--- resources
    --- static
        --- classLevelPath     //behaves as a folder when we use relative path scenario in view names   
            --- test2.html      //this will be used for relative path [case (2)]
        --- test1.html          //this will be used for absolute path [case (1)]
```

2. create a controller class like as the below. This example shows different cases with return `String` and `ModelAndView` in both **relative** and **absolute** path.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/classLevelPath")
public class TestController {

    //case(1)
    @RequestMapping("/methodLevelAbsolutePath1")
    public String absolutePath1(Model model){
        //model.addAttribute();
        //...
        return "/test1.html";  
    }

    //case(1)
    @RequestMapping("/methodLevelAbsolutePath2")
    public ModelAndView absolutePath2(Model model){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/test1.html");
        //modelAndView.addObject()
        //....
        return modelAndView; 
    }

    //case(2)
    @RequestMapping("/methodLevelRelativePath1")
    public String relativePath1(Model model){
        //model.addAttribute();
        //...
        return "test2.html";
    }

    //case(2)
    @RequestMapping("/methodLevelRelativePath2")
    public ModelAndView relativePath2(Model model){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("test2.html");
        //modelAndView.addObject()
        //....
        return modelAndView;  
    }


}
```

**Note:**
You can specify the suffix of your view files by a `ViewResolver` (for example `InternalResourceViewResolver` or `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html` in the `appliction.properties` file of Spring Boot and do not declare `.html` suffix in the above code.

Best Regard