# Controller of Spring MVC does not load my HTML page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, model-view-controller

I'm not able to understand why my simple configuration of `DispatcherServlet` to implement Spring MVC does not work.

My `web.xml` looks like as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The application context of my dispatcher servlet is in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.paolo.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.html</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I have a simple `MyController` to handle the request

```
package org.paolo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String myForm() {
        return "welcome";
    }   
}
```

And under `WEB-INF/views` I put my `welcome.html` page, that is a simple bootstrap form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring | Welcome</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I get an error:
`No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringSecPaolo/WEB-INF/views/welcome.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`

Note that I have both `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` and  `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

Comment: are you trying to access the URL `/SpringSecPaolo/`?

Comment: Since you're just trying to serve static content, you could use the mvc:resources configuration. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources

Comment: @redflar3 localhost:8080/SpringSecPaolo to be precise

Comment: Do you use maven? Have you checked that the welcome.html is really deploeyed? Could you please name the complete directory of the welcome.html file?

Comment: do you need and html file or can you replace it with a jsp?

Comment: please refer to the my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60763901/10976088

Answer (score 1):

You need to request the url to which the controller method is mapped, but not the html view directly!

I guess your application is deployed under: `localhost:8080/SpringSecPaolo` then your controller method with (`@RequestMapping(value="/")` and `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`) gets invoked when you send an HTTP GET to: `localhost:8080/SpringSecPaolo/` (so just enter this url, and the application should send you the html file)

Comment: This is what I am doing but I have a 404, No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringSecPaolo/WEB-INF/views/welcome.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to return a html page with the dispatcher servlet.

`html` files are static and they do not require to be processed by a servlet.

To solve your problem you have two choices:

1. Use html and remove the `InternalResourceViewResolver`
2. Use jsp and use the `InternalResourceViewResolver`

To use html you have to remove the `InternalResourceViewResolver` definition (or set to blank the prefix and suffix attributes) and add this line to the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/views/**" location="/views/" />
```

This will tell Spring to look into views folder for static content.
Then put the views folder under the *WebContent* folder, and
in your Controller *myForm()* method return the html file like this:

```
return "views/welcome.html";
```

To use jsp instead keep the `InternalResourceViewResolver` definition as is and change the suffix property from

```
<property name="suffix">
      <value>.html</value>
</property>
```

to

```
<property name="suffix">
      <value>.jsp</value>
</property>
```

and obviously rename welcome.html to welcome.jsp

For more information about html files and Spring configuration:
 [How to serve .html files with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring)